# SSAS CUBE GIVING ERROR WHILE PROCESSING FROM THE SOLUTION of the CUBE

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, msbi

I am having a cube which have facts and dimension, when I use to process my cube (FULL) from the solution it throws an error:

> 'Errors in the OLAP storage engine: A duplicate attribute key has been found when processing:
>   Table: 'pollux_entities_d_loan_security_master',
>   Column: 'security_desc_1',
>   Value: 'GONDAL ROADRAJKOT'.
>   The attribute is 'Security Desc 1'

I have checked there is no duplicate value in the same table.

Instead of that when i use to process the dimensions separately from the database, and then goes to process the cube from my solution. It throws no error.

I am not getting why is this is happening.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like the dimension in your solution isn't pointing to the table you think it is.

Comment: No i dont think so, and  the error which i was facing ,i updated the same error to NULL and then started the process again...now its working fine.

Comment: Did you check if value for this dimension value 'GONDAL ROADRAJKOT' was newly inserted in fact table and was unavailable in dimension table?